# Date type ticks in quiver plot | matplotlib

Tags: python, date, matplotlib, plot

Usually when I want to have dates in my x-axis in a time series plot in python I take the following approach:

```
ax.plot(time, var)
ax.xaxis_date()
ax.xaxis.set_ticks(time)
myFmt = mdates.DateFormatter('%d %B %H horas')
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(myFmt)
```

Now, I was trying to plot a time series of wind direction with quiver ([example](http://oceanpython.org/2013/03/26/1d-quiver-plot-surface-currents-lobo/)) but it does not allow me to have date type ticks...

I'm trying the following code:

```
ax.quiver(time, u, v, units='y', scale_units='y')
ax.xaxis_date()
ax.xaxis.set_ticks(time)
myFmt = mdates.DateFormatter('%d %B %H horas')
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(myFmt)
```

Is there any way to get the dates in the axis ticks for quiver?